# Rollback transaction knex in if else condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, transactions, knex.js

I have this code using transaction in knex

```
knex.transaction(async trx => {

        try {
            const ids = await knex('team').insert({id: 6, name: "test1"}).transacting(trx);
            const idsNew = await knex('team').insert({id: 7, name: "test2"}).transacting(trx);

            if(condition){
                await trx.rollback();
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
      })
```

when conditon == true I run rollback transaction and database have not new data.
But log throw error `(node:32723) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction rejected with non-error: undefined`

Anyone help me explain this error and help me solve this problem ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When transaction handler function returns a promise (async functions always does that), it means that `knex` implicitly commits / rollsback when that promise resolves / rejects.

That was the first problem with code above. Next problem which from that error message comes is that `trx.rollback()` needs an argument. `trx.rollback(new Error("Condition caused rollback!"));`

Here is code that should work:

knex.transaction(async trx => {

```
    try {
        const ids = await knex('team').insert({id: 6, name: "test1"}).transacting(trx);
        const idsNew = await knex('team').insert({id: 7, name: "test2"}).transacting(trx);

        if(condition){
            // this causes handler function to reject the returned promise
            // and knex will do implicit rollback
            throw new Error("Rolling back because of condition");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
  })
```